# Mock "" received unexpected message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code

```
Class Client 
  def initialize(options = {})
    @key = options['oauth_key']
    @secret = options['oauth_secret']
    @access_token_url = options['oauth_access_token_url']
    @signature_method = options['signature_method']
    @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@key, @secret, {access_token_url: @access_token_url, signature_method: @signature_method})
  end

  def accounts_by_id(account_id)
    response = query_account(account_id)
    parse_json(response)
  end

  private
  def access_token()
    ...
    ...
    ... 
    @access_token = @consumer.get_access_token(nil)
    ...
  end
```

The consumer has been mocked as follows

```
oauth_mock = mock('oauth')
OAuth::Consumer.stubs(:new).returns(oauth_mock)
```

I however get a Mock "oauth" received unexpected message `:get_access_token with (nil)` when i do a

```
GameSystem::Client.new(oauth_key: 'KEY',oauth_secret: 'SECRET',oauth_access_token_url: 'http://localhost').accounts_by_id("kk")
```

The access_token method is called inside query_account.Does anyone know how i could mock that too to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stubbing `OAuth::Consumer.new` to return your mock, but you're not stubbing anything on your mock, so it doesn't have a `#get_access_token` method (or any other methods).  You'll have to stub the methods you want to use on the mock.

```
oauth_mock = mock
oauth_mock.stubs(:get_access_token).returns(whatever)
Oauth::Consumer.stubs(:new).returns(oauth_mock)
```

Comment: Hey Jim ...This helped ..thank you...Didn't realize i posted the question twice